# Why are the dataset and MixHash required for Proof of Work?

Tags: mining, blockchain, proof-of-work, yellow-paper, nonce

From the [yellow paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper); for a block to be accepted as valid, an 8 byte number, n_rand, must be found that satisfies equation 253:

> [image: <code>PoW</code>(H_<strike>n</strike>,n_rand,**d**)[1] _< 2^256/H_d]

[image: H_<strike>n</strike>] = block header without n_rand and MixHash
[image: H_d] = difficulty
[image: n_rand] = nonce

My interpretation is that **d** is the dataset - a value cryptographically derived from the number of previous blocks. From this, the Mixhash is calculated in the `PoW` function

**Why are the dataset and MixHash values required?**

If the network were to agree to accept the `PoW` function with **d** set to 0, wouldn't the system still be cryptographically dependent on valid state transistions, as there must be consensus on H_<strike>n</strike>? Would the system not, therefore, still work?

Comment: Related - http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5833/why-do-we-need-both-nonce-and-mixhash-values-in-a-block

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding, d is, as said in the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) page 6, the current DAG.

Where Hn is the new block’s header H, but without
the nonce and mix-hash components, d being the current
DAG, a large data set needed to compute the mix-hash,
and PoW is the proof-of-work function (see section 11.5):
this evaluates to an array with the first item being the mixhash,
to proof that a correct DAG has been used, and the
second item being a pseudo-random number cryptographically
dependent on H and d. Given an approximately
uniform distribution in the range [0, 2
64), the expected
time to find a solution is proportional to the difficulty,
Hd.

The DAG is necessary to the mining algorithm to ensure the PoW in a n ASIC resistant way and easily verifiable for future light clients.
Here is a full detail of the explanation :

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/master/Dagger-Hashimoto.md

So, you can't set d to 0.

Comment: ... so the system would work if there was consensus for d=0, just not in an ASIC-resistant way?

Comment: The only condition I can see is (from the yellow paper) equation :   (58) , which state that this must be 32 bytes or lower