# How exactly to calculate the Ethereum Mixhash?

Tags: powhash

Sorry I have tried to study the yellow paper, but it sounds quite tough to me.. I know the mixhash is a formation of nonce, but I want to know what exactly "forms" the mixhash(e.g. header + nonce ?) and what's the algorithm and calculation?

Thanks!

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5833/why-do-we-need-both-nonce-and-mixhash-values-in-a-block

Comment: Thanks, I have found this answer before but I want to know the exact "function" to calculate the mixhash and how to generate it with, say, header + nonce, etc.

Comment: The [first google result](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) gives the full specification as well as python code for this

Comment: @TjadenHess and what if this question will be the first google result some day? :-) The idea is to collect all knowledge in one place, and this _could_ be stack exchange in the future.

Comment: This answer is now the first google result... and still now answer.  