# What is the formula to check difficulty on Ethereum genesis block? given ex: genesis block difficulty = 0x0400

Tags: blockchain, mining, genesis, difficulty

I am having trouble understanding something related to calculating difficulty.
Target difficulty is described as `2^256 / difficulty` .

The difficulty of the genesis block is notated as 0x0400 which is equal to 1024.

So if we take 2^256 (115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936)

and divide by 1024 we get : 113078212145816597093331040047546785012958969400039613319782796882727665664

Then we have the block hash for the Ethereum genesis block:
0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3

If you convert this hexadecimal into decimal value it is:
96295644508963302359223866841007920022480890644992946816264522587871600414627

Immediately without a calculation you can tell that the value of the hash  is greater than the value of the target difficulty.
However the documents clearly state:

> If the output of this algorithm is below the desired target, then the nonce is valid

So since we have an output value that is higher than the target, how is the hash on the genesis Ethereum block valid?
Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Where did you see `0x0400` exactly ?

Comment: This is a value I keep seeing thrown around as the genesis block difficulty although finding an official source for it was impossible w the amount of bloat that comes up when I do a search for this topic. Its very possible this is an incorrect value, however if that's the case I would like to know how to verify the real value that was used to calculate the genesis block's target difficulty.

Comment: On etherscan https://etherscan.io/block/0 the genesis block difficulty is at `17,179,869,184` which is `0x400000000` in Hexadecimal.

Comment: Ok. Just to follow my work again here:
were going to take 2^256 and divide the result by 0x400000000 or 17,179,869,184
this results in:   6,739,986,666,787,659,948,666,753,771,754,907,668,409,286,105,635,143,120,275,902,562,304
compared to the int value of the hash:
96,295,644,508,963,302,359,223,866,841,007,920,022,480,890,644,992,946,816,264,522,587,871,600,414,627
the hash is still much larger. How can this hash: 
0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3
be considered lower value than the target?

Comment: Ok so one possibility is that the number 0x400000000 aka 17,179,869,184 needs to have its reciprocal taken before calculating the difficulty. When accounting for this it looks correct, can someone verify if this is the case please?

Comment: You are comparing against the mix hash right ? it's different than the block hash.

Comment: Even though it might be different for the genesis block, not sure about that :/

Comment: Where can I find the block hash then? I am wondering why it is not mentioned on the explorer as it seems like relevant data.

Comment: Anyone reading along, the reciprocal thing was a fake brute force solution, you do not need to take the reciprocal.

Comment: I don't think the mixHash is exposed on Etherscan, the check can be seen here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/ethash/sealer.go#L167 and the actual computation is here : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/8d84a701a5deee92853a50a0ff0ed1aa80aecc3a/consensus/ethash/algorithm.go#L338

Comment: The value that should be below the target is actually `crypto.Keccak256(append(seed, digest...))` where seed is `keccak512(blockHash, blockNonce)` and digest is the mixHash.

Comment: This answer has an explanation how difficulty is evaluated in an ethereum block https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/76900/ (it is not directly related to the block hash).